# Deep-Linking php queries to a data base

Tags: javascript, php

I have been having problems with deep-linking when I want to make a back or forward recall to some php script that involves a query to my data base.
I think that whats happening is that when a link requires a php script that is on a deeper level it doesn't makes the callback to the server. It just works when it uses the same php script that uses the link that was displayed right back or after it.
This is my JS function:

```
function loadload(loc) {
    $("document").ready(function(){
        function loadURL(url) {
            console.log("loadURL: " + url);
            $(loc).load(url);
        }

        // Event handlers
        $.address.init(function(event) {
            console.log("init: " + $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
        }).change(function(event) {
            $(loc).load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
            console.log("change");
        })

        $('a').click(function(){
            loadURL($(this).attr('href'));
        });
    });
};
```

This is my php echo line:

```
echo "<li><a onclick='loadload("."&#34"."#txtHint"."&#34".")' href="."'php/getdaimler.php?q=".$row['Program']."'"."rel="."'address:/Daimler/".$row['Program']."'>". $row['Program']. "</a></li><br>";
```

Also it makes my page become slower when several links have been triggered.
If there are some better functions or methods to use it would be great.
I'll appreciate your answers.

Comment: Can you add some more information about the kind of problem you have? It's a lot easier for us to help you when you say clearly what's going on.

Comment: Yes, I've been trying this for a while, but I've been getting some issues with the history part.

Comment: I read it three times and I still don't understand anything... I think deep-linking (whatever you want to express with this) isn't your problem

Answer (score 0):

The posted jQuery Code can't work like this. First you use an inline event handler (onclick) inside the html code.

```
echo "<li><a onclick='loadload("."&#34"."#txtHint"."&#34".")' href="."'php/getdaimler.php?q=".$row['Program']."'"."rel="."'address:/Daimler/".$row['Program']."'>". $row['Program']. "</a></li><br>";
```

The method you call is `loadload`, the parameter is `&#34#txtHint&#34` which is used as a jQuery selector, but will never match any DOM Element. My best guess is, you want to load the server answer to an element with the id 'txtHint', in that case the selector would be: `#txtHint`.
Now to the jQuery/ javascript function itself:

```
function loadload(loc) {
    // this is wrong, you can not use the event handler for dom ready here...
    $("document").ready(function(){

        function loadURL(url) {
            console.log("loadURL: " + url);
            $(loc).load(url);
        }

        // Where does $.address come from?.... 
        // Event handlers
        $.address.init(function(event) {
            console.log("init: " + $('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
        }).change(function(event) {
            $(loc).load($('[rel=address:' + event.value + ']').attr('href'));
            console.log("change");
        })

        // and here you'll define another click handler - inside the click handler
        // will never be executed...
        $('a').click(function(){
            loadURL($(this).attr('href'));
        });

    });
};
```

Either you use the inline event handler, or a general bind logic, do not mix it.

**Variant a: inline event handler**

```
function loadload(loc,url) {
    console.log("loadURL: " + url);
    $(loc).load(url);
}

echo "<li><a onclick='loadload(\"#txtHint\",\"php/getdaimler.php?q=".$row['Program']."\")' href='php/getdaimler.php?q=".$row['Program']."' rel='address:/Daimler/".$row['Program']."'>". $row['Program']. "</a></li><br>";
```

**Variant b: general binding:**

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
     $('a.loadload',function() {
        $('#txtHint').load($(this).attr('href'));
     });
 });

echo "<li><a class='loadload' href='php/getdaimler.php?q=".$row['Program']."' rel='address:/Daimler/".$row['Program']."'>". $row['Program']. "</a></li><br>";
```

So far for your javascript / html code. To be honest I have no idea if this fits your 'deep link' question, or the db-query you talked about, but it might be a starting point.